# mapbox-map-image-export returns a non-specified error "Error {}" on Ubuntu server

Tags: npm, electron, vps

I have installed the [mapbox-map-image-export](https://github.com/digidem/mapbox-map-image-export) npm package locally in a Ubuntu 18.04 and it work fine to generate the map image.

But when I have installed it in a VPS running under Ubuntu 16.04, it always fail and returns a non-specified error `Error {}`.

It seem like it's something related to electron that fail when the GPU is missing since there is no GPU in a VPS.

I have try everything like `--disable-gpu` or using virtual display server /usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 1280x1024x24' export-map ...

Any ideas?

Comment: You should open an issue in github.

Comment: It's already done :) https://github.com/digidem/mapbox-map-image-export/issues/11